# An array output

Tags: c++, arrays

If I set an array variable a[]="abc" , and then set another array variable b[]={'d','e','f'} ,my last output code is printf("%s",b) ,it's output value is "defabc",why? My output is array b but the output value will output array b first and then output array a second.
The whole code is on bellow.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
  char a[]="abc";
  char b[]={'d','e','f'};
  printf("%s",b);
}
```

The output is "defabc".
And the string length of array b is 7 why?

Comment: i dont see "defabc" as output.

Comment: You don't have a null terminator in b so function reads past buffer and it happens that next on stack is a

Comment: @AdityaK That's the joy of _undefined_ behaviour when programmer does something wrong. ;)

Comment: You'd need `char b[]={'d','e','f', '\0'};`

Answer (score 4):

In C all strings should be null (i.e. `\0`) terminated, so your second variable should look like the following:

```
char b[] = {'d', 'e', 'f', '\0'};
```

You might be curious why `"defabc"` is printed with your code. The answer is, all local variables are stored in a [stack-based memory layout](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/). So your memory layout looks like this:

```
|'d' | <-- b
|'e' |
|'f' |
|'a' | <-- a
|'b' |
|'c' |
|'\0'|
```

Also note that `printf("%s", ...)` reads until it reach a `\0`, so `printf("%s", a)` works as expected but `printf("%s", b)` prints `"defabc"`.

Comment: I would not mention stack data structure but [memory organisation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation). Data structure is not relevant here

Comment: @OlegBogdanov You're right "data structure" is for different purposes!

Comment: It means that a="abc" its really value is "abc\0" right?

Comment: @Pulsar Yes. `"abc"` is stored in memory as 4 bytes `'a' 'b' 'c' '\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a null terminator at the end of both strings. your second string does not have it as its defined as an array of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Correct ways to declare a string

```
char b[] = { 'd', 'e', 'f', '\0' };    // null terminator required
```

or

```
char b[] = "def";    // null terminator added automatically
```

So, this code will print `def` as output

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a[] = "abc";
    char b[] = { 'd', 'e', 'f', '\0' };
    printf("%s", b);
    return 0;
}
```